# Unable to install NodeJS in Jenkins on runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Configured NodeJS in Globally

[image]

On runtime, it display, "node command not found ..."

[image]

Comment: Ugh, I don't know if it's that but it might be the "usual" problem with Linux. Possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882988/node-command-not-found-on-debian and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593902/node-command-not-found but there are others. Basically, the problem is that there is an old `node` package in the Linux repos which is completely different to NodeJS. So when the latter is installed, it makes sure to not break the former and you have to do it yourself. I don't know if that's exactly your issue but it seems to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Node.JS installation entries in your build log. Most likely you have not configured Node.JS installation in the Build Environment section. In your config the tool is defined with the "4.2.3" name. Jenkins' Node.JS plugin does not use a single specification as a default one, hence it just falls back to a tool from the environment.

[Screenshot from the Wiki page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONLQQ.png)

Comment: Is there links to show how to configure NodeJS installation in the Build Environment section?

Answer (score 0):

I've used a temporary fix for this in my MAC machine;  but really expecting an apt answer for this.

---

Here is the temporary fix,

Setup temporary environment for node in `Execute shell`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

[image]