# I can not run console log in VSCode

Tags: javascript, macos, visual-studio-code

I am brand new, have recently learned `HTML` and `CSS`. After starting `JavaScript` i tried to run this and check it in `console` log.

```
// variables

// numeric
var x = 1

x = 24

console.log(x)
```

I am using `VSCode` and installed `Code Runner`. I right clicked to run code and receive this error msg.

```
[Running] node "/Users/C/Desktop/Project 02/src/index.js"
/bin/sh: node: command not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.021 seconds
```

Not sure what to do and I basically started trying to learn `Javascript` today.

I am using a `MacOS` - Catalina if that helps.

Thank you for any input and I apologize if this has been asked before, since I just joined Stackoverflow today.

Edit:
Thank you for all the help. I needed to download Node.js that fixed the issue.

Comment: You need to install the node.js runtime. https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: Please refer this thread for answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593902/node-command-not-found

Comment: JS is a dynamically typed language, so you don't need to use a syntax for declaring types, only the scope, using the three mentioned variable types in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install NodeJS on your Mac

[nodejs download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Answer (score 1):

Although the syntax is correct, I would recommend defining a variable by the following

There are 3 ways to define a variable:

- `let`
- `var`
- `const`

For your example, we will use `let`, the modified syntax is given below:

```js
let x = 24
console.log(x);
```

Secondly, you need nodejs, download it from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and run `node .`

Comment: Nothing wrong with his syntax, he's just reassigning x after instantiating it to 4

Comment: someone edited the question, earlier it had a syntax error, check edits

Comment: `x = 24` is just fine from the syntax point of view, it'll just assign the variable to the global scope.

Comment: oh okay ill have my answer changed, also i didnt know about this, thank you

Comment: I would strongly recommending against using `var` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var